# Story about knight who had super-powered vision and right arm

Tags: story-identification, novel, medieval

I wonder what is the name of the story I read years ago.

Setting is medieval-like. Story starts with torture of the main character where he loses arm and eye.
Another detail I remember is that he fought several god-like creatures and acquired eye from one of them, and an arm from another.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Writing this I remembered that one of the chapters called "Queen of swords". Googling pointed to Wikipedia page on tarot but also on Michael Moorcock's Corum character.

This is [wiki intro into series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Corum_Jhaelen_Irsei):

> Corum is a Vadhagh, one of a race of long-lived beings with limited magical abilities dedicated to peaceful pursuits such as art and poetry. A group of "Mabden" (men) led by the savage Earl Glandyth-a-Krae raid the family castle and slaughter everyone with the exception of Corum, who escapes. Arming himself, Corum attacks and kills several of the Mabden before **being captured and tortured. After having his left hand cut off and right eye put out, Corum escapes** by moving into another plane of existence, becoming invisible to the Mabden.